# gpg bad signature clear text

Tags: gpg, pgp

How do you verify a clearsign signature if all you got is the person public key and their clearsign signature, say from an email without a source file.

For ex:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

My message is here.
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.14 (GNU/Linux)

iJwEAQECAAYFAlWxhrEACgkQ7UsYmEPWfkECmwP/alQ025erUVowZqe3PB8YE37H
mKiFTyVLWDyTSYHo7IJBCHww0xDVt8VvZ1CdoDzDWYFlWuxLSa6G1G8Flbmhq5kD
UNmkazt7p4m+CK7+fkHzYjcmbtf5KAMnJP2ieQLwwrMuRN/GsUUmgdLszor67WP5
o4JEdXKnrErFBUeMaNs=
=e17S
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

After I import the public key. And copy and paste that into a file called input.txt. And doing a gpg --verify input.txt. I get a gpg: BAD signature. Is it even possible to verify without a source file?

Comment: What do you mean by "source file"?  The message is there. It's not a _detached_ signature. If `gpg2 --verify` says the signature is bad, then either the message or the signature has been tampered with (or you have failed to save it correctly to the file).

Comment: All I did was copy and paste the message into a file. You think it's possible that I copy it wrong? I did a test on a local file and one single mispell will bring a bad signature error. I'm not sure what I did wrong except the message is not from the same source as the key.

Comment: did you happen to do this "copy and paste into a file" on a windows box?  or using a word-processor rather than a text editor?

Comment: I paste it straight into a nano editor on the server using putty. Is that bad?

Comment: Note that if you copied the message out of a word processor, such as Microsoft Word, it may well have made automatic changes to the message (like changing straight quotes into typographical quotes, or removing "unnecessary" trailing whitespace on lines, or even _joining_ lines into paragraphs).